# how would I route url with and anchor to a specific controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, url-routing, laravel-routing

I've inherited a site which uses JSON and uses hashes to expand boxes.
Which is causing me an issue when I am creating shares.

I can create an end-point url and that works fine except the way the site is written it pulls in the data in a different fashion.

only Google has this issue because you can only give it a share url to get the information.

I've been trying to figure out how to parse a laravel rout to a controller when the posted url looks like this.

```
http://somesite.com/#gen/mag/aritcle-name/
```

the part I want to catch is just the - #gen

these do not work, however I imagine there is some kind of escape I have to do...

```
Route::get('/#gen/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('#gen/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('/\#gen/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('/[#gen]/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('/[\#gen]/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('/(#gen)/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
Route::get('/(\#gen)/mag/', array('uses'=>'content@helloworld'));
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Andi

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960513/using-a-hash-within-a-url-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser won't send anything after a # in the end of the url. This can only be handled in javascript:

```js
var hashContent = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: Hi there, I thought so and that's why I couldn't find any documentation to do this server side. It was worth asking in case anyone had found a way round it.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.